# eventListener to alter between two elements

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is whenever I `mouseover` on an element for it to set the style of `video` to `display: none;` and then the `img` to `display: block;`

Here's my code:

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
        alternate(event);
    });
    document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
        alternate(event);
    });

    function alternate(e) {
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (target) {
            if (target.nodeName == "IMG") {
                target.querySelector(".video").style.display = "block";
                target.querySelector(".img").style.display = "none";
            } else if (target.nodeName == "VIDEO") {
                target.querySelector(".video").style.display = "none";
                target.querySelector(".img").style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
        <li>
            <div>
                <video class="video" src="./test.mp4" type="video/mp4" muted autoplay></video>
                <img class="img" src="./test.jpg"></img>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <video class="video" src="./test.mp4" type="video/mp4" muted autoplay></video>
                <img class="img" src="./test.jpg"></img>
            </div>
        </li>
</div>
```

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is whenever I `mouseout` from the video, put the image back and then back from. `video: hidden, image:shown` to `video:shown, image:hidden`.

**I did manage** to get something working by using the `target.previousSibling` technique but it didn't work 100%,

*Hopefully I formatted this question right, thank you for reading. Any help is really appreciated.*

Comment: Why are you using Javascript for this? CSS would solve this for you for free.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with pure CSS. A very simple approach would be:

```css
.hover-toggle {
  position: relative;
}

.hover-toggle .video {

  /* Use absolute positioning to place video along-side image */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  /* Set video to be transparent by default */
  opacity: 0;
}

/* When hovering the transparent video, cause it to become opaque */
.hover-toggle .video:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-toggle">
  <video class="video" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" muted autoplay></video>
  <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x176" />
</div>

<div class="hover-toggle">
  <video class="video" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" muted autoplay></video>
  <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x176" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are the proper events to use.
- If you use `<li>` then you must use `<ol>` or `<ul>` as the parent.
- Register the events to each `<li>`

  ```
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (let item of items) {
    item.addEventListener('mouseenter', alternate);
    item.addEventListener('mouseleave', alternate);
  }
  ```
- Define the event handler using `e.target` and `.matches('li')` to insure that the events only apply to `<li>`. Then use `e.type` to insure that only `mouseenter` and mouseleave` events apply.

  ```
  const tgt = e.target;
  const evt = e.type;

  if (tgt.matches('li')) {
    if (evt === 'mouseenter') {
    ...
    else if (evt === 'mouseleave') {
    ...
  }
  ```
- The reason why `target.previousSibling` worked some of the time is because `display: none` removes elements from the flow thereby not being recognized as a sibling. Try assigning a class that has `visibility` and `z-index` properties and alternate that class between events.

  ```
  tgt.children[0].classList.add('on');
  tgt.children[1].classList.remove('on');
  // and vice versa
  ```

BTW `<img>` tags are void elements (no end tag <del>`</img>`</del>)

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let item of items) {
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', alternate);
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', alternate);
}

function alternate(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const evt = e.type;

  if (tgt.matches('li')) {
    if (evt === 'mouseenter') {
      tgt.children[0].classList.add('on');
      tgt.children[1].classList.remove('on');
    } else if (evt === 'mouseleave') {
      tgt.children[1].classList.add('on');
      tgt.children[0].classList.remove('on');
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  height: 135px;
}

li * {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.on {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <video src='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005610.mp4' muted autoplay loop width='240' height='135'></video>
    <img class='on' src='https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png' width='240' height='135'>
  </li>
  <li>
    <video src='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4' muted autoplay loop width='240' height='135'></video>
    <img class='on' src='https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png' width='240' height='135'>
  </li>
</ul>
```